# If elseif elseif else logic with html & php code the elseif conditon are not executing

Tags: php, html, cakephp-1.3

I have code with some situation to first check then code should execute according to it. my code has

```
<?php if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')==''){ ?>
  <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Start now" onclick="javascript:register_popup();">
  <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Start now" onclick="javascript:submitPlan(2);">
  <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Start now" onclick="javascript:submitPlan(3);">
<?php } elseif($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')!='' && $this->Session->read('Auth.User.role_id')=='3' && isset($this->data['User']['plan_type']) && $this->data['User']['plan_type']=='A'){ ?>
   <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Your plan" onclick="javascript:register_popup();">
   <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Start now" onclick="javascript:submitPlan(2);">
   <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Start now" onclick="javascript:submitPlan(3);">
<?php } elseif($this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')!='' && $this->Session->read('Auth.User.role_id')=='3' && $this->data['User']['plan_type']=='B'){ ?>
   <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Start now" onclick="javascript:register_popup();">
   <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Your plan " onclick="javascript:submitPlan(2);">
   <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Start now" onclick="javascript:submitPlan(3);">
<?php } else{?>  
   <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Start now" onclick="javascript:register_popup();">
   <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Start now" onclick="javascript:submitPlan(2);">
   <input class="profilebtn" type="button" style="width:100px !important; margin-top: 1px;" value="Your plan" onclick="javascript:submitPlan(3);">
<?php } ?>
```

So I have 3 button in each condition so according to user already plan I want to change button value from start now to your plan & rest 2 button should have start now option. So in this code what happening its checking if condition   not match then directly going to execute of else not checking the else if part which I want to check first.

Comment: `var_dump($this->data['User']['plan_type']);` what do you see?

Comment: Just so it's said: you could set the button text in a bit of code before this, and you wouldn't have but one set of buttons like `<input type="button" value="<?= $button_text['A'] ?>" onclick="register_popup()">` etc.  (BTW, those inline styles might be better as a `#containerId input.profilebtn` rule in CSS.  And you don't need `javascript:` in onclick attributes.)

Answer (score 0):

The elseifs will only run if the values satisfy all of the conditions. If they are not executing, then at least one of the conditions is not being met.

For example, can you say for sure that the variables here:

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')!=''
&& $this->Session->read('Auth.User.role_id')=='3'
&& $this->data['User']['plan_type']=='B')
```

are all indeed as you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make another elseif with (true) as condition. So you can check if the elseif works itself. 
If it jumps into that, there is something wrong with both of your conditions.

Manually check your variables with something like

```
var_dump($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role_id')=='3');
```

and check if the output is as you plan in the conditions.